# flatten an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-structures, flatten

I have a data structure that looks like this

```
const array = [{
    name: 'bar',
  children: [{
    name: 'foo',
    children: [{
        name: 'baz123',
    }, {
        name: 'baz',
    }]
  }]
}, {
    name: 'shallowKey'
}, {
    name: 'abc'
}];
```

And I would like to flatten it to look something like this

```
[{
    name: 'bar'
}, {
    name: 'foo',
}, {
    name: 'baz123',
}, {
    name: 'baz',
}, {
    name: 'shallowKey'
}, {
    name: 'abc'
}];
```

I tried lodash like this https://jsfiddle.net/hmzhjji/081q60qg/1/
But it's not doing anything, any other way I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: That fiddle doesn't use lodash

Comment: I'm currently trying to come up with something in the same fiddle, sorry

Comment: I assume any object here can have children that can also have children that can also have children and so on?

Answer (score 4):

A recursive way would be:

```
 function flatten(array, result = []){
   for(const {name, children} of array){
     result.push({name});
     if(children) flatten(children, result);
   }
  return result;
}
```

Or the alternative ES6 version:

```
 const flatten = array => array.reduce((res, {name, children = []}) => res.concat(name).concat(flatten(children)), []);
```

So you can do `flatten(array)` to get the desired result.

Comment: @federico do you think that an explanation will help here? `this iterates over the array, destructures each element and pushes its name into the result, the  proceed with its children` <- thats exactly what the code tells you

Comment: @darshan why should i??

Comment: @JonasW. you know what? You're right and I'm sorry. But it's too late for me to retract the downvote (unless you edit your post).

Comment: @JonasW. personally because a lot of questions are karmawhoring instead of trying to be helpful to the OP. This was not the case, but the prevalence of certain answers made me trigger happy. I don't know what other people think.

Comment: I'm sorry, but am I missing something? the code is not really that complex to require documentation. It can be such a pain to explain some simple code especially if you're just helping someone out

Comment: @JonasW. and OP in fact I removed the downvote and apologized because, again, this answer didn't really have the problem I was mentioning :)

Comment: @aspiring_dev `explain your code` is one of the unwritten laws of SO which i do not understand

Comment: @JonasW. there's been [ample discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) about that. Again, this was not the case with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach to iterate over the array and check if the required object is present and call the function recursively

```
const array = [{
    name: 'bar',
  children: [{
    name: 'foo',
    children: [{
        name: 'baz123',
    }, {
        name: 'baz',
    }]
  }]
}, {
    name: 'shallowKey'
}, {
    name: 'abc'
}];


var res = [];
function flatten(array){
   array.forEach(function(obj){
       var name = {name: obj.name}
       res.push(name);
       if(obj.children){
          flatten(obj.children)
        }
    })
    return res;
 }


 console.log(flatten(array))
```